# Open related video from IFrame Player in the same page

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

When a YouTube video stops playing, related videos are often shown at the end in a grid (depending on the video owner's preference). I have an IFrame Player embedded on a web page that plays public YouTube videos. When a related videos at the end is clicked, a new page is opened playing the related video. I've scoured the API docs and although there doesn't seem to be a solution, I'm going to ask anyway in case I've missed something or some perspective. Is there an API setting that allows the video to play on the same iframe instead of opening a new page, or some solution that could be worked out?